# Manament MS sql from one IP

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want manament ms sql 2005 server from one ip (my home) and denice all another ip. Guide me

Answer (score 0):

Either RDP to the server, or setup a VPN connection between your home computer and your production server.

You never want to expose SQL Server directly to the public internet.